# apps/music/photo sync **after** clean install of iOS 7

Tags: ios, data-synchronization, upgrade, data

I am preparing to upgrade to iOS 7.0+ via a clean install. From what I've read, this method is best to minimize the chance of taking a hit on battery performance. If I understand correctly, a clean install wipes my phone and puts it into a "brand new, just out of the box state."

My question is - do I just re-sync my clean phone using iTunes to get my music and photos (stored in iPhoto) back on my newly upgraded phone? If this isn't correct, can someone please respond with the best method or direct me to a site that will offer the instructions?

Comment: I've tried to clean this up but it's kind of a yes/no question, but maybe a good answer could be added elaborating on how apps store data. We strongly prefer people don't put thanks and signatures in the post.

Comment: If you are planning to re-sync your apps/music/photos back to your device, do you really need to do a clean install? …or do you not want to sync app *data* back to your device?

Comment: I don't really care about app data, as I only have a few such as Dropbox, Camera+ and the gmail app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can "Set up as new iPhone" and later sync apps, music, photos, movies, books, etc., from iTunes. You will lose all app data, including the data stored in the iOS stock apps that Apple provides.

Keep the following in mind to be better prepared before you do this:

1. You will have to configure all settings afresh (including settings like WiFi, Privacy, Location Services, Notifications, Mail accounts, iMessage, iTunes & App Store, Safari, Do Not Disturb, Passcode, Restrictions, and others).
2. Import photos from the Camera Roll before the new phone setup. Otherwise you will lose all those photos (even if you have photostream enabled, you may probably lose older photos if they're not synced to another device)!
3. You will lose all Messages (iMessages, SMS/MMS), Call History, Mail Accounts, Calendar Accounts, Wallpapers and the Home Screen arrangement of app icons.

For a complete list of what the iOS backup contains, which in this case is all that you would lose and have to setup afresh, see the section titled [iTunes will back up the following information](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT4946) on Apple's "iTunes: About iOS backups" page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. When you do a clean install of iOS 7 no to your device, iTunes will prompt you to set up your device. When asked to restore from backup, choose **Set up as new iPhone**. This will mean that you don't restore your data and preserve your 'fresh' install.

[image]

Use the tabs across the top of iTunes to select exactly what you would like to sync back to your device. Apps that you sync to your device using the Apps tab in iTunes do not restore the app data, unless the app data is stored in iCloud, or through some other method of syncing data (i.e. Dropbox content that is pulled from Dropbox servers).

Comment: The beauty of a clean install is you get to see all the new settings in their default state and also keep a backup stored on iCloud (or a backup copy of the iTunes data) in case you want to restore the backup after a few days on the clean install.

Comment: bmike and grgarside, Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I appreciate your thorough replies.